# What is best practice organize a MVC project with backend, frontend and web api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structure, asp.net-web-api

I have a question about organizing a ASP.NET MVC project.

I have 3 different main area. Front and back-end, and I have a Web API.

I want to know what is best practice for organizing such a project?

What I have done so far is to make 3 different projects so I could separate the area of which they worked on, but I have a problem with the Web API with CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).

So my question would be, is it possible to have 3 projects, or should I have to use areas? I still want to be able to separate the "concerns" (Web API, fronted, back-end).

Comment: have you tried looking through the web? Do that first and then please ask specific questions.. you will come across many blogs written about this..

Comment: here is one I ran into on googling: http://www.mostlydevelopers.com/blog/post/2011/07/28/n-Tier-Architecture-Introduction-Part-1.aspx

Comment: I dont think you understand my question.

Comment: I am already using a N-Tier model, but I have 3 different "presentation"/UI-layers. My question is how should i organize such a problem. Right now I have 3 different UI (MVC 4) projects in my solution, but this give me a CORS problem for the Web API, because they all run on differents ports in IIS Express.

Comment: why dont you run it all under one default virtual directory.. your structure would be http://localhost => virtual root, localhost/Web1. localhost/Web2, localhost/Web3 and run them all under IIS and not IIS express

Comment: Thank you! :) Tried changing it to use IIS 7. Got a little help from a reply here http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/113323/how-to-run-your-visual-studio-web-applications-with-iis-7-instead-of-default-virtual

You are welcome to post a answer. :)

Comment: The result: http://imgur.com/fAw2T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you run it all under one default virtual directory.. your structure would be localhost => virtual root, localhost/Web1. localhost/Web2, localhost/Web3 and run them all under IIS and not IIS express